# SQL query in Qliksense

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, load, qliksense

I have the following query

SQL

```
SELECT * from HIVE.`abc`.`def`
    WHERE concat(cast(`year` as String),'-',lpad(`month`, 2,0),'-',lpad(`day`, 2,0)) IN
     (select max(concat(cast(`year` as String),'-',lpad(`month`, 2,0),'-',lpad(`day`, 2,0))) 
     from HIVE.`abc`.`def`);
```

I want to divide this query into two parts and execute it.
I checked this in Hue, the query throws an error. But if I spilit the query it is working fine like,

```
select max(concat(cast(`year` as String),'-',lpad(`month`, 2,0),'-',lpad(`day`, 2,0))) 
 from HIVE.`abc`.`def` ;
```

**This will return 2020-04-19**

Now

```
 SQL SELECT * from HIVE.`abc`.`def`
WHERE concat(cast(`year` as String),'-',lpad(`month`, 2,0),'-',lpad(`day`, 2,0)) IN '2020-04-19';
```

This works fine. But I want to use a variable or alias in WHERE clause. I want to run this query to find the latest partition on daily basis.

I am working in Qliksense load editor. I am fetching data from HIVE database.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Andrew Connector reply error: SQL##f - SqlState: S1000, ErrorCode: 35, ErrorMsg: [Cloudera][Hardy] (35) Error from server: error code: '2' error message: 'Error while compiling statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 2, vertexId=vertex_1621684473298_49194_2_00, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1621684473298_49194_2_00 [Map 2] killed/failed due to:ROOT_INPUT_INIT_FAILURE, Vertex Input: abc initializer failed, vertex=vertex_1621684473298_49194_2_00 [Map 2], org.apache.hado

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the SQL  using inner join. Hive sometime doesnt support inner clauses.

```
SELECT * from HIVE.`abc`.`def`
JOIN 
(select max(concat(cast(`year` as String),'-',lpad(`month`, 2,0),'-',lpad(`day`, 2,0))) maxdt from HIVE.`abc`.`def`) rs 
ON concat(cast(`year` as String),'-',lpad(`month`, 2,0),'-',lpad(`day`, 2,0)) =rs.maxdt
;
```

I tested in my hive, its working. Pls note, i used all data type as int.
[image: testing]

Alternate SQL

```
SELECT * from t
JOIN 
(select max(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat(cast(`year` as String),lpad(`month`, 2,0),lpad(`day`, 2,0)) ,'yyyyMMdd'))) maxdt from t) rs 
ON from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat(cast(`year` as String),lpad(`month`, 2,0),lpad(`day`, 2,0)) ,'yyyyMMdd')) =rs.maxdt
;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately I get the same error. Is there any solution to solve this.

Comment: I tested it in my system, you can see its working. So, could you please see your column data types and hive version.

Comment: Thanks. Yes the year,month,date is int in my HIVE table as well. But i am not able to execute it.

Comment: whats your hive version? mine - 2.1.1

Comment: Also i do not like the idea of maxing the string. May be convert it to a timestamp and then compare. Could you try alternate sql?

Comment: I tried the alternate SQL, It says nullpointerexception.

Comment: select max(concat(cast(`year` as String),'-',lpad(`month`, 2,0),'-',lpad(`day`, 2,0)))  as maximum
 from HIVE.`abc`.`def` ; Is there any way to use this maximum alias in SQL WHERE clause.